# how to integrate a vue js project within a django project?

Tags: django, vue.js

I have an existing vue js project and for backend I want to use django, what came to my mind was to use rest api to communicate with the backend without any integration. is that what everyone is doing or my approach is old school and I have to put the vue project in django directory and go through the whole collectstatic thing?
sorry if my question is too basic.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

i don't know hows people doing, usually me and my team did like the python just access the index.html from the Vue build folder when production mode.

but in development mode, we just separate two of them. the python running as the endpoint API (need to enable cors mode in dev), and the Vue run in development mode.